# How do i turn values of characters from a given String of parens into Integers depending if their order is correct?

Tags: java, stack

The task is to set the given string of parens example: "(())" to numbers 0,1 and -1.

Number 0 would be an Integer for "(" if the given paren "(" has it's pair ")" in the given String.
Number 1 would be an Integer for ")" if the given paren ")" has it's pair "(" in the given String.
Number -1 would be an Integer for "(" or ")" if none of them has a pair or to be precise if they are not closed in the given String.
For example:

```
1.Input:      2.Input:      3.Input    ​
(()           ())           ((())(()))))
Output:       Output:       Output:
-101          01-1          0001100111-1-1
```

I  have tried using a  stack to check if  parens were in  the correct order but i am not able to  set the values for them depending  on the  condition.

```
String parens="(())";
        Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
        char c;

        for(int i=0;i<parens.length();i++) {
            c=parens.charAt(i);
            if(c=='(')
                s.push(c);
            else if(c==')') {
                if(s.empty() || s.peek()!='(')
                    continue;
                else
                    s.pop();
            }
        }

        if(s.empty()) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
```

Comment: This is hard because you don't know if the leading `(` has a match or not based on the matches further down the string.  You'll need to track the position of such characters in the "number" and then go back and adjust them later based on the result at the end.

Comment: I'm also curious if braces can match parenthesis or those two need to be tracked independently.  It'll add further complication if it's the latter.

Comment: @markspace I think the braces were a mistake.  The examples only show parens.

Comment: I will fix that typo.Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you general idea is correct - it needs to be adjusted to fit the main task "convert braces to numbers".

Let's take next assumptions for solving the task:

- temp array of result strings by index will be used
- stack for holding indexes of opened (and not yet closed) braces will be used

Algorithm will be next:

1. Iterate over given string using next rules:

- If stack is empty and char at current index is ')' - "-1" for current index
- If stack is empty and char at current index is '(' - push current index into stack
- If stack is not empty and char at current index is ')' - set result for current index as "1" - and also pop element (matched open brace index) from stack at set result for poped index as "0"
- If stack is not empty and char at current index is '(' - push current index into stack

2. After iterating over string - for each element in stack - result should be "-1"
3. Combine all the results into 1 string

Code:

```
private static String convert(String input) {
    String[] result = new String[input.length()];

    Stack<Integer> openPositions = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char currentChar = input.charAt(i);

        if (openPositions.isEmpty()) {
            if (currentChar == ')') {
                result[i] = "-1";
            } else {
                openPositions.push(i);
            }
        } else {
            if (currentChar == ')') {
                result[i] = "1";
                result[openPositions.pop()] = "0";
            } else {
                openPositions.push(i);
            }
        }
    }

    openPositions.forEach(index -> result[index] = "-1");

    return String.join("", result);
}
```

Comment: I believe you made a typo.  `result[openPositions.pop()] = "1"; `should be `result[openPositions.pop()] = "0";`

Comment: Thank you a lot, it did work and it is a great addon to the idea i had! :D